# State of Judaism before the destruction of the first temple

Tags: history, judaism

Can someone recommend some good resources on delving into the state of Judaism between entry to Israel and the destruction of the first temple? Specifically, the state of the religion. What did it look like in all aspects, halachically and hashkafically.

I very much wish to know what the average Jew's relationship with Hashem looked like back then, as well as what their daily religious schedule might have looked like, what the family and societal dynamics were, and their general worldview, zeitgeist and umwelt - ideally all comparative with other periods in our history.

I am especially keen to try and find out what we have lost since then, possibly as punishment and a result of our the distancing in our relationship with Hashem.

Comment: Are you looking for a jewish sefer or a research sort of book?

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy I understand quite little is known from that time so I am tempted to say anything, but to bring more focus - whatever answers my above questions the best

Comment: It would seem that quite a lot about that can be gleaned from the Nach and Kesuvim. Are you looking for something external to that?

Comment: @user9806 yes please

Comment: I mean Melachim and Yirmiyahu will be the main source for much of the info ,no?

Comment: @sam yes and no, as they weren't written with the goal of conveying the information I want, although it will be there to some degree

Comment: Rabbi Ouri Cherki has some perspectives on the subject. He thinks that the Zohar reflects what the common Jew believed during the time of prophecy and how he related to Hashem. Nowadays the common Jew has difficulty grasping the Zohar because we are all on a much lower level and are far from a world where prophecy was an everyday thing.

Comment: @Harel13 that's actually going well with the reasoning behind my question and my suspicions. Would you be able to find me a link or 2? Good shabbos

Comment: I'm not entirely sure in which class I heard it, but I'm pretty sure it's in one of these: https://meirtv.com/shiurim/206967/, https://meirtv.com/shiurim/208412/. The classes are in Hebrew.

Comment: @Harel13 I'll watch bli neder. Never heard of him, I'd like to find if maybe he has a sefer where he goes into more detail

Comment: He's very well-known in Dati (Modern Orthodox) circles in Israel, and also among the international Noachide community because he's the chairman of Brit Olam, the world Noachide organization. He has students who run his website, if you want to check it out (parts of it are in English): http://ravsherki.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=101300.

Comment: @Harel13 if you read this letter regarding closely, regarding the point about Bavel, I think you might find it interesting and relevant to this question, and your suggestion: https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7949/jewish/Epistle-4.htm